# How to fix ajax request/response for mobile browsers in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[code shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QYTc.png) This code perfectly works in desktop browsers,but for mobile browser  directly redirect to url location,not works in my below code...To click on submit button form input data sent to process-data.php via submit-data.js and response shown to span

```
 **form.php**                           
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>    
<script src="js/form/submit-data.js"></script>    

<form id="feed_<?php echo$type_id;?>" action="include/process_data.php" method="post">    
<input type="hidden" name="cmd_<?php echo$type_id;?>" value="<?php echo$type_id; ?>">    
<input type="hidden" name="item_<?php echo$type_id;?>" value="<?php echo $type_name;?>">    
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo$type_id;?>" value="<?php echo $ac_p;?>">    
<input type="submit" class="fa fa-chevron-down" value="Submit">    
</form>    
<span id="dFcn_<?php echo$type_id;?>"></span>
```

**submit-data.js**

```
//submit-data.js        
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $('form').submit(function(event) {    
    var charid = this.id;    
    var idsplit = charid.split('_');    
    var getid = idsplit[1];    
    var cmsd=$('input[name=cmd_'+getid+']').val();    

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class    
    $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text    
    // get the form data    
    var formData = {    
        'cmd'               : $('input[name=cmd_'+getid+']').val(),    
        'item'          : $('input[name=item_'+getid+']').val(),    
        'amount'    : $('input[name=amount_'+getid+']').val()    
    };    
    $.ajax({    
        type        : 'POST',    
        url         : 'include/process_data.php',    
        data        : formData,    
        dataType    : 'json',    
        encode      : true    
    })    
    .done(function(data) {    
        //console.log(data);     

        if ( ! data.success) {    
            // errors message    
            $('#dFcn_'+cmsd+'').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');    
        } else {    
            //success message!    
            $('#dFcn_'+cmsd+'').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');    
        }    
    })    

    //stop refreshing the page    
        event.preventDefault();    
    });    

});
```

**process_data.php**

```
  <?php    
//array    
$data= array();    

if (empty($_POST['cmd']) && empty($_POST['item']) && empty($_POST['amount']))    
    $POST_DATA_FALIURE = 'POST DATA FALIURE';    

if ( ! empty($POST_DATA_FALIURE)) {    
    $data['success'] = false;    
    $data['errors']  = $POST_DATA_FALIURE;    
} else {    
    $data['success'] = true;    
    $data['message'] = 'SUCCESS MESSAGE';    
}    
echo json_encode($data);    
?>
```

Comment: Please add your code here as text, not as an image. It allows us to better analyze and test the code.

Comment: okay, the code is in text:                                                                                            // process the form
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
 url: 'include/process_data.php',
 data: formData,
 dataType: 'json', 
 encode: true
}) .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            if ( ! data.success) {
                //error msg from process_data.php
            } else {
                //success msg from process_data.php
            }

Comment: You should [edit] your question with the text. Also, explain more fully on what is happening, and what is not working.

Comment: i have edited my question in detail,where ajax response shown to span tag in desktop browser,but not for mobile browser [ here, targeted url directly shown,like simple form action]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the form was in table "td" tag and in the same page too many js conflict,
after removing external linked js (given below), that's worked for me in cross browser.
**[Note:] However by this technology we can generate multiple form in while loop and send multiple form-data and get each form submitted response over ajax without page reload,Thank you.**

```
[these js was linked for making table responsive,data search type]    
DataTables 1.10.19    
Bootstrap integration for DataTables' Responsive    
Responsive 2.2.3    
FixedHeader 3.1.5    
DataTables Bootstrap 3 integration
```